# Pass parameter to custom field in joomla

Tags: joomla

I create a custom field which gets related people,subjects of an article when I edit it.I want to pass the category id of this article , but I can't figure out how to do it. Below is my code: 
In article.xml

```
<fields name="idn_tags">
        <field name="idn_tags_people" type="IdnTagsPeopleCheckboxes" />
        <field name="idn_tags_subject" type="IdnTagsSubjectCheckboxes" />
</fields>
```

In edit.php

```
<?php echo $this->form->getInput('idn_tags_people','idn_tags'); ?>
<?php echo $this->form->getInput('idn_tags_subject','idn_tags'); ?>
```

In every class IdnTagsPeopleCheckboxes and IdnTagsSubjectCheckboxes I want to pass category id of current article to get only people, subjects of this category which article maybe tagged.

Comment: it look like your are make a joomla module? am i right?? and which version of joomla you are using??

Comment: I am newbie, I just wanna edit comp_content in administrator. I'm using joomla 2.5.7. I think the problem is how to override method getInput to pass the parameter, but i can't :|

Answer (score 1):

Joomla has already covered adding custom fields to the article component [***Read this***](http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component).
If you have any issues let me know. ***[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168932/how-do-you-add-fields-to-com-content-in-joomla-with-a-plugin-and-store-the-data)*** as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok! Just do this:

```
<?php $this->form->setValue('idn_tags_people','idn_tags', $[Your Value]); ?>
<?php echo $this->form->getInput('idn_tags_people','idn_tags'); ?>
```